# Using LANDFIRE data in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am wanting to use the LANDFIRE rasters in QGIS, but I cannot get all the files to load.  I load the w001001.adf file in the directory that contains the data, but I cannot access the attribute table, change the style, etc.

I have searched around in Google and have not found an answer.

Happy to give more info!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a QGIS issue. You should report it on the [QGIS issue tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues).

I've tried a couple of ArcInfo Binary Grids and QGIS reads them but won't access the attribute table.  However, GDAL (which QGIS uses to read the grids) reads the table just fine...

```
$ gdalinfo test
Driver: AIG/Arc/Info Binary Grid
Files: test
       test.aux.xml
       test/w001001x.adf
       test/hdr.adf
       test/log
       test/dblbnd.adf
       test/w001001.adf
       test/vat.adf
       test/metadata.xml
       test/sta.adf
Size is 250, 250
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (0.000000000000000,250.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (       0.000,     250.000) 
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Upper Right (     250.000,     250.000) 
Lower Right (     250.000,       0.000) 
Center      (     125.000,     125.000) 
Band 1 Block=256x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = test
  Min=1.000 Max=1.000 
  NoData Value=255
<GDALRasterAttributeTable>
  <FieldDefn index="0">
    <Name>VALUE</Name>
    <Type>0</Type>
    <Usage>5</Usage>
  </FieldDefn>
  <FieldDefn index="1">
    <Name>COUNT</Name>
    <Type>0</Type>
    <Usage>1</Usage>
  </FieldDefn>
  <Row index="0">
    <F>1</F>
    <F>62500</F>
  </Row>
</GDALRasterAttributeTable>
```